# Компиляция кода для любой операционной системы

Tags: python-3.x

Я скомпилировал код python в exe файл, выбрал компиляцию одним файлом, он запускается на моем компьютере, но если попробовать запустить на другом, с другой версией windows, то выдает ошибка, как это можно исправить?

Ожидал что будет запускаться на всех версиях windows, думаю может как то компилировать сразу с необходимыми для работы файлами

Comment: Какая ошибка-то? И какая версия Python? Поддерживает ли выбранная вами версия питона те операционные системы, на которых вы пытаетесь его запустить?

Comment: Ах да, и что такое «на всех версиях Windows»? Вы уверены, что ваша программа обязана запускаться на Windows 3.11 например?

Comment: запуск программы невозможен так как на компьютере отсутствует api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll компилировал на windows 11, ошибка на windows 7

Comment: если через установщик сделать, может получится?

Comment: Устанавливаете версию Python, поддерживающую Windows 7 (это Python 3.7), на нее устанавливаете Pyinstaller, потом собираете вашу программу этим pyinstaller-ом